# How can I make sure my iframe takes the whole width and height of the screen, regardless of any width restrictions

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe, widget

I have a widget that I built using an iframe, which I give it to users like this

```
<div style="height: 100px; width: 100px">
    <iframe src="https://jade-biscuit-7026ef.netlify.app/?productId=LprOsWjrho5B&type=popup" style="border: 0;"
      height="100vh" width="100vw"></iframe>
  </div>
```

so users can set the height and width in the container div as shown above. My problem now is, in the iframe, I have a modal that opens up on click of a button, so i want this modal to take up the full width and height of the user's screen but instead, it is restricted by the dimensions of the containing div

below is the code in my iframe:

```
/** @format */

import {
  Modal,
  ModalOverlay,
  ModalContent,
  ModalBody,
  useDisclosure,
  Box,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import CheckoutInfo from "./CheckoutCard";
import { Button } from "mainstack-design-system";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { TPaymentOptions, TProductDataRes } from "types";
import StripeCardCheckout from "./StripeCardCheckout";

interface IProps {
  width: string | null;
  productId: string;
  btnText?: string;
}
const PopupCheckout = ({ width, productId, btnText }: IProps) => {
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();
  const [openModal,setOpenModal] = useState(false)
  const [paymentOption, setPaymentOption] = useState<TPaymentOptions>("");
  const [productData, setProductData] = useState<TProductDataRes>(
    {} as TProductDataRes
  );

  const ipAddress = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("userIp"));
  const isNigerian = ipAddress?.currency === "NGN";

  useEffect(()=>{
    setOpenModal(true)
  },[])
  return (
    <>
      <Button
        variant="primary"
        onClick={onOpen}
        label={btnText ?? "Proceed to checkout"}
        size="medium"
      />
      
      <Modal isOpen={openModal} onClose={onClose}>
        <ModalOverlay />
        <ModalContent
          className="modal"
          borderRadius={'0.75rem'}
          maxWidth={width}
          // w={"95%"}
          // maxH={"90vh"}
          overflow={"scroll"}
        >
          <ModalBody padding={0}>
            <CheckoutInfo
              hasBorder
              hasCancel
              closeModal={() => setOpenModal(false)}
              paymentOption={paymentOption}
              setPaymentOption={setPaymentOption}
              productId={productId}
              setProductData={setProductData}
            />
            {paymentOption === "card" && !isNigerian && (
              <StripeCardCheckout
                setPaymentOption={setPaymentOption}
                productData={productData}
                closePopup={() => setOpenModal(false)}
              />
            )}
          </ModalBody>
        </ModalContent>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};

export default PopupCheckout;
```

and below is how a user can call it:

```
<div style="height: 100vh;">
    <iframe src="https://jade-biscuit-7026ef.netlify.app/?productId=LprOsWjrho5B&type=popup" style="border: 0;"
      height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Potential Solution: add styling to modal and iframe itself..

```
import {
  Modal,
  ModalOverlay,
  ModalContent,
  ModalBody,
  useDisclosure,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import CheckoutInfo from "./CheckoutCard";
import { Button } from "mainstack-design-system";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { TPaymentOptions, TProductDataRes } from "types";
import StripeCardCheckout from "./StripeCardCheckout";

interface IProps {
  width: string | null;
  productId: string;
  btnText?: string;
}
const PopupCheckout = ({ width, productId, btnText }: IProps) => {
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();
  const [paymentOption, setPaymentOption] = useState<TPaymentOptions>("");
  const [productData, setProductData] = useState<TProductDataRes>(
    {} as TProductDataRes
  );

  const ipAddress = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("userIp"));
  const isNigerian = ipAddress?.currency === "NGN";

  useEffect(() => {
    onOpen();
  }, [onOpen]);

  return (
    <>
      <Button
        variant="primary"
        onClick={onOpen}
        label={btnText ?? "Proceed to checkout"}
        size="medium"
      />

      <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose} size="fullScreen">
        <ModalOverlay />
        <ModalContent
          className="modal"
          borderRadius={'0.75rem'}
          maxWidth={width}
        >
          <ModalBody padding={0}>
            <CheckoutInfo
              hasBorder
              hasCancel
              closeModal={onClose}
              paymentOption={paymentOption}
              setPaymentOption={setPaymentOption}
              productId={productId}
              setProductData={setProductData}
            />
            {paymentOption === "card" && !isNigerian && (
              <StripeCardCheckout
                setPaymentOption={setPaymentOption}
                productData={productData}
                closePopup={onClose}
              />
            )}
          </ModalBody>
        </ModalContent>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};

export default PopupCheckout;
```

iframe

```
return 
(<div style="height: 100vh;">
  <iframe
    src="https://jade-biscuit-7026ef.netlify.app/?productId=LprOsWjrho5B&type=popup"
    style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"
    onLoad={(e) => {
      const iframeDocument = e.target.contentDocument;
      const styleTag = iframeDocument.createElement('style');
      styleTag.innerHTML = `
        /* Add your custom styles here */
        body {
          margin: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
        }
      `;
      iframeDocument.head.appendChild(styleTag);
    }}
  ></iframe>
</div>)
```

Comment: in a case where the user didn't specify the div's height to be 100vh, would it still work

Comment: do you mean in the wrapping div? applying 100% and or 100vh to wrapper and iframe you can guarantee it takes up the entire screen

Comment: yeah that works but i'm just thinking , in case the user wants to put the widget in a particular section of their website, how will that be done knowing that we've set the height of the widget to 100vh

Comment: If it works/answers your question make sure to mark as answered so others know your original question is answered! 
Secondly, if you allow the modal to be resizeable or draggable then the user can easily modify it in the UI - you can also implement logic if you would like to do it manually or you can even add a toggle for users etc but might as well let the UI libs do all that work

Answer (score 0):

you can set inline style to give the `iframe` "width"  and "height" of `100%` of its parent

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the iframe to fill the screen, then the following CSS could be added to it while displaying the modal.

```
position: absolute,
top: 0,
left: 0,
height: 100vh,
width: 100vh,
overflow: hidden
```

You would then remove this when the modal is closed.

However, the more normal way of doing this would be to have a JS file in the parent page that displays the modal when needed and use the [postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to communicate between the iframe and the code in the JS file.